# Angular2 hide infoWindow

Tags: typescript, angular

I am working with this library: https://angular-maps.com/

Now I all ready show and hide a div on marker and map click. But I also want to close the infowindow when `mapClicked` is executed, here a Plunker: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/djvrrBxov2Pq83DihC22?p=preview)

```
mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    this.isClicked = false;
 }
```

This all ready triggers the boolean to false but if I set `*ngIf="isClicked"` on the infowindow `<sebm-google-map-info-window` than it will not open.

Here the `isClicked` will be set to true:

```
<sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let location of locations" (markerClick)="updateDiv(location)">
```

here the updateDiv function:

```
 updateDiv(location: Location) {
    this.isClicked = true;
    this.selectedLocation = location;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hacky solution! Not the best but it is working, I give it a try with jquery like this:

`$('.gm-style-iw').next('div').find('img').click();`

This will represent a click on the [x] in the infowindow

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `open()` on the info-window element.

```
<sebm-google-map-info-window #infowindow
```

```
@ViewChild('infowindow') infoWindow;
```

```
  mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
        this.isClicked = false;
        this.infoWindow.open();
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uNDEeI6Zj1c1rxhSTmP6?p=preview)

Comment: I tried what you did with .close() but it is not working. And do you have to declare @ViewChild('infowindow') infoWindow: any;?

Comment: `.close()` is working the same. I haven't found anything that allows to get the current status (opened/closed) which makes it hard to use. http://plnkr.co/edit/lMA3Tnu6k4oJLOfnZ40B?p=preview breaks when you close the infowindow using the `[X]` in the info window. You can use `@ViewChild('infowindow') infoWindow:SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow`

Comment: hmm, so it is almost impossible to close the current opened infowindow

Comment: It's easy to close it. It's just not easy to know whether it is open or closed.

Comment: Ahh **** thats what I want :(

Comment: what do you prefer me to do?

Comment: I'd create a bug report to get that feature (reading the infoWindow` opened status) added. Besides that. I don't see a way to solve this. Maybe you can remove the `[x]` button from the infowindow by some configuration, so that `mapClick()` is the only means to close the infoWindow, then you can be sure the state maintained by your code is correct. I don't know this angular-maps library. I just looked up the docs a bit to be able to answer your question.