# Angular2 how to hide infoWindow when other gets opened

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an infoWindow overlay which I create to append a div to the parent of a google maps class.

Now I want to close it when an other infoWindow get opened, what I have tried is this:

```
lastClicked: SebmGoogleMapInfoWindow;
if (this.lastClicked){
    console.log(this.lastClicked);
    this.lastClicked.close();
}
```

But in this discussion [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486673/angular2-hide-infowindow) you see it was not working than I came up with an hacky solution like this:

```
$('.gm-style-iw').next('div').find('img').click();
```

But is there a possible way to close the current opened infoWindow when an other gets opened

Here a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/xIccop?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
(markerClick)="updateDiv(location, infowindow)"
```

And then within updateDiv method

```
updateDiv(location: Location, infoWindow) { <== pass current infoWindow
  ...
  if (this.lastClicked && this.lastClicked !== infoWindow){
     this.lastClicked.close();
  }
  this.lastClicked = infoWindow; <== add this line
}
```

See your updated plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/QZLs74?p=preview

Comment: Nice, but try to click a marker than click outside(somewhere on the map) to close it and try to reopen the same infowindow again

Comment: Thats because of the hacky solution of closing when clicking outside. Is it possible to close it the same way when clicked on map?

Comment: And why did you do it like that and not passing the variable infoWindow in mapClicked?

Comment: I have edited my marker to an overlay-view, but now it will see it as a mapClick and will immediately close the infoWindow. Do you maybe know a solution?

Comment: Please add plunker

Comment: How do I do that, I have changed the core of ang2-google-maps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609567/angular-2-how-do-i-pass-data-from-an-component-to-an-service-with-inputs#answer-37619331

Comment: ahh because it is missing rxjs/Observer how do I implement this?\

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/oe2y5awa2kg4vx69iAOo?p=preview As you see when I click on the marker it opens and closes immediately. How do I create a workaround

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658542/angular2-infowindow-hides-when-clicked-on-marker

Comment: Why is that? could you please explain? And what did you exactly do, just added the $event? But than you doing nothing with it??

Comment: Click on custom div (overlay view) bubles unlike just marker. So i add stopPropagation in OverlayViewBla.draw `google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click",...`

Comment: OKay your the best !! Thanks a lot going to do research on the stopPropagation not completely clear yet:)

Comment: Sorry, i removed `isClicked` from plunkr accidentally

Comment: Np mate thanks after all:) I've got one more question, is it hard to initialize infoBox.js in my project? Because I all ready have an class for the OverlayView

Comment: yo man maybe you could help me out on this, iam really deperate! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742203/angular-2-get-current-zoom-level-of-map