# Angular 2 how do I pass data from an component to an service with inputs?

Tags: typescript, angular

First of all I have an interface which looks like this:

```
 export interface OverlayViewOptions {
   position: LatLng|LatLngLiteral;
   map?: GoogleMap;
   draggable?: boolean;
   objectId?: string;
}
```

I do get the position passed by Inputs, now I want to pass the objectId

Here the Class where I need the data:

```
 export class OverlayViewBla {
      public latlng : any;
      overlayView: any;

  constructor(options: any, google: any) {
    console.log(options);


    var self = this;
    this.overlayView.draw = function() {
      var div = this.div;

      if (!div) {

        div.innerHTML = '<span class="number-id">9</span>';

    }
  }

  getOverlayView() : any {
      return this.overlayView;
    }
}
```

And the directive google-map-overlay-view.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'sebm-google-map-overlay-view',
  inputs: ['latitude', 'longitude', 'objectId'],
  outputs: ['markerClick', 'dragEnd']
})
export class SebmGoogleMapOverlayView implements OnDestroy,
    OnChanges, AfterContentInit {

  latitude: number;

  longitude: number;

  objectId: string;
```

Here is the createOverlayView in file named google-maps-api-wrapper.ts:

```
  createOverlayView(options: mapTypes.MarkerOptions = <mapTypes.MarkerOptions>{}):
    Promise<mapTypes.OverlayView> {
      return this._map.then((map: mapTypes.GoogleMap) => {
         console.log('options');
         var overlay = new mapTypes.OverlayViewBla(options, google);
         var overlayView = overlay.getOverlayView();
         overlayView.setMap(map);

         return overlayView;
    }
  );
}
```

And here the addOverlayView method in file named overlay-view-manager.ts

```
export class OverlayViewManager {
  addOverlayView(overlayView: SebmGoogleMapOverlayView) {
     console.log(overlayView.idObject,'test'); // where this is undefined
      const overlayViewPromise = this._mapsWrapper.createOverlayView({
      position: {lat: overlayView.latitude, lng: overlayView.longitude},

    });

    this._overlayViews.set(overlayView, overlayViewPromise);
  }
```

and the html template where objectId needs to be the id input:

```
<sebm-google-map-overlay-view *ngFor="let location of locations" [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [objectId]="location.id"></sebm-google-map-overlay-view>
```

and the app.component.ts:

```
locations: marker[] = [
{id: '1',  lat: 51.5239935252832,    lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
  ]
```

How do I pass the id like I pass the lat and long

Comment: What's not working the way you do it? What's the service you want to pass the id to?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I want to pass it to the export `class OverlayViewBla`

Comment: it is not working because I need to write something to use that input and pass it. But I do not know how..

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer How can I create a plunker with edited core of angular2-google-maps?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm not very good with JS environment because I only use Dart myself.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer maybe you could look at this repository: https://github.com/smgjreinieren/angular-2-google-maps-overlayView

Comment: It might be easier to get an answer if you remove all code that isn't absolutely necessary. It's quite difficult to figure out what the question is about at all with all that noise.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Like this?

Comment: You don't need `var self = this` if you use `(x) =>` instead of `function(x)`. With `=>` `this` just works.

Comment: Looks better but still seems to contain unnecessary stuff. The whole interface seems to be an implementation detail that is not related to the problem. I'm not able to figure out how the `OverlayView` class and the `createOverlayView()` function are related to the `objectId` you need in the template.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Iam passing parameters in `new mapTypes.OverlayViewClass()` where i am also passing the lat and lng

Comment: `createOverlayView()` is a method of `SebmGoogleMapOverlayView`? In this case please fix the formatting of the code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I wrote the file names with it so you can see they are in seperate files

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what the problem is about.

Comment: Do you get any error message? Why would passing `id` be different than `lat` and `long`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I dont know how to pass the id of that array in my app.component to class OverlayViewBla. Because it is a custom code from a colleague. I have to define it etc

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer maybe you could look at the github link and look at the code in app/vendor/angular2-google-maps/directives & services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where exactly you went wrong. Probably here in `google-maps-api-wrapper.ts`:

```
createOverlayView(options: mapTypes.MarkerOptions = <mapTypes.MarkerOptions>{}):
```

Should be `OverlayViewOptions` instead of `MarkerOptions`.

Moreover i created the plunkr for you https://plnkr.co/edit/5RhqdjzjKhYzqvjvDj4p?p=preview

Hope it helps!