# angular2 infoWindow hides when clicked on marker

Tags: typescript, angular

I have created a custom marker and now it thinks that if I click on the marker it is mentioned als mapClick: here a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/oe2y5awa2kg4vx69iAOo?p=preview)

```
mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    this.isClicked = false;

    console.log(this.isClicked);

    if(this.lastClicked) {
        this.lastClicked.close();
        // this.lastClicked = null;
    }
}
```

Does somebody know a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an `event.stopPopagation()` in the addDomListener in google-map-types.ts => `google.maps.event.addDomListener(div, "click", function(event: any) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(self.overlayView, "click");
            event.stopPropagation();
        });`