# Angular 2 get current zoom level of map

Tags: google-maps, typescript, angular

I have a custom map which match the markers on the exact same position where they belong but when I zoom in the markers or the map is a bit shifted. Now I use an `overlayview` as an marker, which class is in the file google-maps-types.ts thats where I set the center point of the marker. So What I really want is to get the current zoom there to make an if statement, to change the center point with each zoom.

Here is a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BoZyeMqRfbLuOCW8ZXG?p=preview), so basically what I want is to get the current zoom level in google-map-types.ts so I can acces that and change the point of the marker. Or vice versa, get the position of the marker in directives/google-map.ts.

But I do not think thats a proper way of doing this, I want to update its position (shift a little bit up) when zoom is changed..

as you see at this image at zoom level 18 the markers are a little bit shifted:[image]

What I have tried in google-map-types but I really do not want to edit it in the class OverlayViewBla:

```
this.overlayView.getZoom = function () {
  console.log(this._mapsWrapper);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this._mapsWrapper,'zoom_changed', function(event: any) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(this._mapsWrapper, "zoom_changed");
    console.log(this._mapsWrapper);
    var zoom =  this._mapsWrapper.getZoom();
    console.log(zoom);
  });
}
```

And this is btw not working.
Or simply add ...px to the top position of the overlay, thats what I want to do in google-map.ts what are good options?

If anyone could help me out on this you will help me a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`google.maps.OverlayView` supports function `getMap()`, as indicated by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView). So getting the zoom level from within your overlayView object should be as simple as:

```
this.overlayView.getZoom = function () {
  var my_map = this.overlayView.getMap();
  if(my_map){ //sometimes, the map might not be set yet, it gets set only after you add the overlay to map
      return my_map.getZoom();
  }
  return null;
}
```